# Web-based fantasy action game reminiscent of Times of Lore

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I was reminded today of a Web-based video game that I think I played about fifteen years ago.  It was not that long or that fancy, but I rather enjoyed it.  Given the time frame and what I remember about the game, I think it was probably a Flash game—which, unfortunately, means that there is a good chance that it may have entirely ceased to exist.

It reminded me somewhat of *[Times of Lore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_of_Lore)*, in that the game had a square map that included a number of small towns and wilderness areas that you gradually explore, in the course of completing a number of missions that you are assigned.  Over the course of the game, the stakes involved in the missions become higher and higher, culminating in battles with evil forces that are appearing throughout the land—invading from another plane or dimension.  I don't really remember anything about the player character's abilities, such as whether he used melee weapons or some kind of ranged attack.

Unlike *Times of Lore*, I think the view was from directly overhead, with no angled perspective view.  I remember thinking that the enemies looked similar to those in the original *[Gauntlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauntlet_(1985_video_game))*, with reaching arms.  However, there was not a lot of detail in the enemies' sprites, except for their outlines; they were mostly of a single color, with perhaps a few embellishments.  The final boss was fought in the ruins of town in the precise center of the map.  I think his wide and seemingly multi-limbed shape (a palette swap of an earlier boss enemy) reminded me of an overhead view of [*Mortal Kombat*'s Goro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goro_(Mortal_Kombat)).